# Filtering of data in signal processing

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing

I am processing the data from serial. I have to filter the data to remove ripples. I have tried with the following code. However, I can't get the expected results. Suggest me which type of filter I have to use?

```
def graph_plot():
    plt.xlabel("samples")
    plt.ylabel("data")
    plt.xlim([0, 2048])
    plt.ylim([0, 255])
    return plt

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(1, which = 'both', axis = 'y', markevery = 5)

actual_rx_data = rx_data[4:2052] #rx_data is input from serial
N = len(actual_rx_data)
rx_data = [actual_rx_data[i] for i in range (0, N)]
rx_data = np.reshape(rx_data, (2048, 1))

smoother = ConvolutionSmoother(window_len = 20, window_type = 'ones')
smoother.smooth(rx_data)

plt = graph_plot()

ax.plot(rx_data, color = 'red')  #input 
ax.plot(smoother.smooth_data[0], linewidth = 2, color = 'blue')  #output
ax.clear()
```

Result obtained by the above code:
[image: Result obtained by the above code]

Expected results in blue color:
[image: Expected results in blue color]

Comment: Consider posting this to [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another site